# How did China dub and air The Twins of Destiny?

Tags: animation

[*The Twins of Destiny*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twins_of_Destiny) is a 1991 animated series that depicts Chinese Empress Dowager as a villain:

> The Twins of Destiny (known as Les Jumeaux du Bout du Monde (The Twins of the Edge of the World) in French, or 天命神童 (Destiny's Children) in Chinese) was a 1991 animated television series produced by French writer Jean Chalopin. It followed the fictional quest of two children, Jules and Julie, in their travels across Eurasia seeking to overthrow the Empress Dowager of China, and consequently, release their fathers from imprisonment.

But how did China which has severe censorship policies dub and air this series?

From other part of the article:

> The animation was translated and introduced to China in mid-1990s.

Also, the series has a Chinese name as mentioned in the first quoted text.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem - perhaps you can explain more why you think it is strange why it was aired in China?  The Monarchy of China is not the same ruling elite as the Chinese Communist Party - and while the CCP did not fight and abolish the monarchy, I would think that ideologically they wouldn't be supportive of monarchy.

Comment: Also the wikipedia article is kind of vague mentioning "China" and "Chinese".  I think its pretty likely that *does* in fact mean the PRC and Mandarin, but it is not 100% sure, and may have aired in (for example) Taiwan / RoC.

Comment: @iandotkelly Either way, it seems like both the KMT and CCP were and are anti-empire. So the same reasoning would apply to both nations that call themselves "China". I believe that currently on Wikipedia and in the foreign policy of most governments "China" refers to the mainland PRC and some variation on "Taiwan ROC" is used for the other.

Comment: However, in the case of this series, it was bought, dubbed and aired in the PRC.

Comment: Good to know @blobbymcblobby... I couldn't find that.  I agree with ToddWilcox that it doesn't really matter, the CCP is not sympathetic to the Monarchy of the Chinese Empire anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 1949, China has been ruled by the Chinese Communist Party (CCP). While the CCP did not exist when the last imperial dynasty of China was overthrown in 1912, they do trace their movement back to Sun Yat-sen, who was a significant republican opposed to the empire.

In other words, the CCP seems to lean more anti-imperial, not pro-imperial. We wouldn't normally expect them to censor anti-imperial sentiment, such as what appears in *The Twins of Destiny*. On the contrary, a story of overthrowing the empress in favor of some kind of (people's) republican government is much closer to pro-CCP propaganda.

You might get deeper understanding by asking about the official CCP position on the Machu dynasty and empire on the politics stack.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR:

It is a product of its origins (French-Japanese) and of the time (early 90s).

The PRC had no animation industry then, having been decimated by the preceding decades political turmoil, so in order to feed the local market, the networks turn to the international market - which is dominated by US, Japanese, and French-Japanese collaborations.

In that market there was very little content at the time that either featured China or its ancient history, myths and legends, so there was very little choice for product that could be bought, dubbed and modified for the local PRC audiences.

So basically this series could dub and air at the time because there was very little else and the networks required content that could not be fulfilled locally (Even Star Trek episodes were airing at this time; Doraemon (Japanese animated character) too, which was problematic since the character is seen as politically subversive, yet it was a popular broadcast).

That just isn't the case now, where the PRC has its own (government supported) animation industry and the censoring authorities are very much in control of output. And the market conditions necessitating the import of foreign titles has long gone.

OP states:

> series that depicts Chinese Empress Dowager as a villain

The long standing narrative of the PRC is also that Empress Dowager is seen as a villain. Not much conflict there.

So,

> How did China dub and air The Twins of Destiny?

Easily. The dire state of the local animation industry and the requirements of the market dictated that a popular, already produced series, that has performed well internationally and features China in its story, means that this was ripe for dubbing and airing in the PRC at the time.

...........

The PRC in the 90s was out of the shadow of Deng and was under the leadership of Jiang Zemin and the third generation of political players. PRCs economic reform was in progress and the capital market, the PRC place on the global stock exchange was considered stable, the financial sector had been liberalized. The Reforms and Opening-up program was in full swing, where PRC growth showed qualities that are normally associated with democracies and not the PRC of the Mao era. The PRC government reduced tariffs and other trade barriers, resulting in increased foreign investment. Foreign relations between the PRC and the world at large at this point were warmer than before.

The PRC *had* an animation industry, it was even internationally recognized at one point, but the countries turmoil at the hands of Mao in the 1960s essentially killed it off.

With no industry to speak of, the networks looked to import their animation series and features. Two players at this point were very big in the international market - Japan and France. These two countries would collaborate on many projects together, and one man was very important in that partnership: Jean Chalopin

As a writer and producer he was responsible for a number of familiar France-Japan (and US) co-productions:  Inspector Gadget, The Mysterious Cities of Gold, Ulysses 31, Heathcliff, Care Bears, Jayce and the Wheeled Warriors, MASK, etc.

Jean Chalopin headed a world wide group producing and distributing these titles, that included offices in the PRC. With internationally popular titles the PRC networks went to him to import titles that could not be produced internally.

> China’s animation industry fell silent during the turbulence of the late 1960s and didn’t re-emerge until the rise of a market economy and government support helped it sputter back into life in the late 1990s. In the meantime, Japanese animated films and TV series captured the imagination of audiences all over the world, including in China

The 1980s and 1990s animation market was dominated by US, French-Japan collaborations, and Japanese animation. Even given the Euro-centric content, the dubbing and airing of this series proved popular.

What also proved useful is that the story showed the  Empress Dowager in a negative light, and in the PRC, for many years, the mainstream view of Empress Dowager Cixi was that she was a devious despot who contributed in no small part to China's slide into corruption, chaos, and revolution.

Today, when people look back at this series, people note fond memories of the music and the characters but the French angle and perception draw ire from the modern day audience.

It is simply a sign of the times.

In the last decade and a half, censorship policies and the perception of the Chinese people to the outside world, in other words, face and national identity and national pride became incredibly important, and that is why a series like that would be unlikely to be given the leeway it did back in the 90s, in a very different era (and not for the reasons you would think).

Thus:

*Could you dub and air this in the PRC in the 90s? Yes.*

*Could you dub and air this in the PRC now? Possibly not without changes.*

https://movie.douban.com/subject/2969831/

https://movie.douban.com/subject/2969831/discussion/22644921/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Chalopin

https://www.screendaily.com/features/how-chinas-animation-industry-is-evolving-to-appeal-to-global-markets/5140298.article

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Chinese_animation

https://factsanddetails.com/china/cat7/sub42/entry-7610.html